# Javascript console.log returns c() instead of the values of the object

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, observable, console.log

I'm trying to use console.log to get the value of the `self.subcategories` object after it is created in the subscribe function below.  I always get `c()` in my console from the `console.log(self.subcategories)` below.  I know that the data is there, as I can use it in a different piece of code.  I just want to be able to see it in console.log so I can get more info and know what to do with it.

```
function QuestionFilter(data, categories, getSubcategoriesByCategoryUrl, getQuestionsBySubcategoryUrl) {
  var self = this;
  self.categories = ko.observableArray(categories);
  self.subcategories = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();

  self.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(category) {
    function search(nameKey, myArray){
      for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].parentCategory_id === nameKey) {
          self.subcategories.push(myArray[i]);
        }
      }
    }   
    search(category, categories);
    console.log(self.subcategories);
  });
};
```

The Knockout.js library is included and so there are a couple of references to it.  As I mentioned, everything works, I just want to be able to log the object to help me write more code.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is not enough code to help you. Where is `ko.observableArray()` for example.

Comment: @putvande: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Ah thanks, maybe OP should mention he/she is using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Reading information from an observableArray**
>
> Behind the scenes, an `observableArray` is actually an observable whose value is an array (plus, `observableArray` adds some additional features described below). So, **you can get the underlying JavaScript array by invoking the `observableArray` as a function** with no parameters, just like any other observable. Then you can read information from that underlying array. For example,
>
> ```
> alert('The length of the array is ' + myObservableArray().length);
> alert('The first element is ' + myObservableArray()[0]);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking there was just something simple about Javascript that I didn't know.  I thought that calling the object was enough, since it referenced the observable.  I just added `()` and it worked.

So, `console.log(self.subcategories());` gave the desired output.

Comment: Javascript is a langauge, KO is a library. Huge difference